# get True Positives, TN, FP and FN for arrays in Python

Tags: python, evaluation, confusion-matrix

my data set result look like this

```
yval
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

and predicted results look like this

```
y_pred
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to find the TP, TN, FP, and FP

I tried this

```
cm=confusion_matrix(yval, y_pred)
```

which gave this error

```
ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

tried this

```
cm=confusion_matrix(yval.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1))
TN = cm[0][0]
FN = cm[1][0]
TP = cm[1][1]
FP = cm[0][1]
```

gave zeros for all values `TN=0, FN=0, TP=0 and FP=0`

how can I get these values for a predicted array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arrays TP, TN, FP and FN in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964473/arrays-tp-tn-fp-and-fn-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix` to import multilabel confusion matrix.
After that the drill is:

```
cm = multilabel_confusion_matrix(yval, y_pred)
```