# arrays TP, TN, FP and FN in Python

Tags: python, arrays, confusion-matrix

My prediction results look like this

**TestArray**

```
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,...,1,0,1,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,...,0,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,...,0,1,1,1],
.
.
.
[1,1,0,1,1,0,1,...,0,1,1,1],
```

**PredictionArray**

```
[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,...,1,0,1,1],
[1,0,1,1,1,1,0,...,1,0,0,1],
[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,...,1,1,1,1],
.
.
.
[1,1,0,1,1,0,1,...,0,1,1,1],
```

this is the size of the arrays that I have

```
TestArray.shape

Out[159]: (200, 24)

PredictionArray.shape

Out[159]: (200, 24)
```

I want to get TP, TN, FP and FN for these arrays

I tried this code

```
cm=confusion_matrix(TestArray.argmax(axis=1), PredictionArray.argmax(axis=1))
TN = cm[0][0]
FN = cm[1][0]
TP = cm[1][1]
FP = cm[0][1]
print(TN,FN,TP,FP)
```

but the results I got

```
TN = cm[0][0]
FN = cm[1][0]
TP = cm[1][1]
FP = cm[0][1]
print(TN,FN,TP,FP)

125 5 0 1
```

I checked the shape of cm

```
cm.shape

Out[168]: (17, 17)
```

125 + 5 + 0 + 1 = 131 and that does not equal the number of columns I have which is 200

I am expecting to have 200 as each cell in the array suppose to be TF, TN, FP, TP so the total should be 200

How to fix that?

Here is an example of the problem

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


TestArray = np.array(
[
[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1],
[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
[1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0]
])

TestArray.shape



PredictionArray = np.array(
[
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
])

PredictionArray.shape

cm=confusion_matrix(TestArray.argmax(axis=1), PredictionArray.argmax(axis=1))
TN = cm[0][0]
FN = cm[1][0]
TP = cm[1][1]
FP = cm[0][1]

print(TN,FN,TP,FP)
```

The output is

```
5 0 2 0
```

= 5+0+2+0 = 7 !!

There are 20 columns in the array and 10 rows

but cm gives to total of 7!!

Comment: Did you check the shape of `cm`?

Comment: yes, i edited my question with cm shape

Comment: can you add reproducible example?

Comment: @DavidS I added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `np.argmax` the matrices that you input `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` isn't binary anymore, as `np.argmax` returns the index of the first occuring maximum value. In this case along `axis=1`.

You don't get the good'ol true-positives / hits, true-negatives / correct-rejections, etc., when your prediction isn't binary.

You should find that `sum(sum(cm))` indeed equals 200.

---

If each index of the arrays represents an individual prediction, i.e. you are trying to get TP/TN/FP/FN for a total of 200 (`10 * 20`) predictions with the outcome of either `0` or `1` for each prediction, then you can obtain TP/TN/FP/FN by *flattening* the arrays before parsing them to `confusion_matrix`. That is to say, you could reshape `TestArray` and `PreditionArry` to `(200,)`, e.g.:

```py
cm = confusion_matrix(TestArray.reshape(-1), PredictionArray.reshape(-1))

TN = cm[0][0]
FN = cm[1][0]
TP = cm[1][1]
FP = cm[0][1]

print(TN, FN, TP, FP, '=', TN + FN + TP + FP)
```

Which returns

```
74 28 73 25 = 200
```

Comment: So you suggest not to use TestArray.argmax(axis=1) ?